# What does Dwarf Therapist let me do that I couldn't do in the game?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What does Dwarf Therapist let me do that I couldn't do in the game or manually in a spreadsheet and tediously in the native client?

Comment: you don't need to have this in two places, delete one.

Comment: it's been so long (almost 3 years) I have no idea

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taken from the project on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/dwarftherapist/)

- Persistent custom professions - import and manage any number of custom professions across all your forts.
- Assign multiple dwarves to a custom profession at once to unify active labors
- Manage labors and professions much more easily than in-game using a flexible UI, allowing quick review of all dwarves at-a-glance
- Display all pending changes before they're written to the game
- Sort labor columns by associated skill level
- Persistent and customizable display; change colors, reposition/hide information screens
- Group your dwarves by several criteria

Comment: none of these things I couldn't do by looking up all the information in the game, manually entering into a spreadsheet, sorting, and updating through the client, right?

Comment: @antony.trupe It doesn't directly do anything that you couldn't do in game, certainly. It does provide features that reduce tasks that in-game might require 100 keystrokes and reduce it to a couple clicks.

Comment: @JavadocMD much the way glider reduced WoW from 100s of keystrokes to a couple clicks...

Comment: @tzenes: Haha, I wouldn't say *quite* the same way.

Comment: @JavadocMD I realize that was a bit of a specious comment, but the point I was trying to get across is that reducing the tasks in DF is like using a car to win a Marathon; kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: Not even close; it's more like using some kind of scheduler to keep track of your energy levels, the amount of oxygen in your lungs and the perfect stride length in order to maximize your speed over the duration of the marathon.

Answer (score 7):

[Dwarf Therapist's Vision](http://code.google.com/p/dwarftherapist/wiki/VisionStatement)

"*What DwarfTherapist is not:*

DwarfTherapist is not intended to undermine the game designers’ intentions of how the game mechanics, balance, or logic works and as such DwarfTherapist as not a hacking, cheating, or ‘game modding’ tool. DwarfTherapist also is not intended to create a ‘game outside of the game’ in manners that extend game functionality (such as command-chaining or macros) or otherwise introduce new gaming elements outside of Dwarf Fortress that are not immediately and conspicuously tied to the primary and secondary design intentions."

Comment: I'm curious as to who downvoted this.  The reason @Antony put this here is because he doesn't believe this to be cheating (as I do).  While others disagree it is certainly "on topic" and not worth a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

It let's you save 30+ minutes when managing 80+ dwarves.

*More Time Playing, less time managing.*